# Function Quantification and Set Theory

Tags: logic

A lot of authors have statements along the lines of, "There exists a function such that..." It's my understanding that first order logic, including set theory, can't quantify over relations, functions, or predicates. Is there a way that such statements can be represented formally on set theoretic grounds? Or should we be content with informal proofs involving such statements?

Comment: In set theory, functions just are certain sorts of sets. And the domain of discourse in set theory ranges over, well, sets, of course. From this point of view, it is perfectly legitimate to write, in first-order logic, $\exists x\cdots$, where $x$ is thought of as ranging over sets.

Comment: What about the case for subsets of the domain?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. For *any* domain of discourse you choose, first-order logic allows you to quantify over individuals in that domain; it doesn't allow you to quantify over sets of individuals in that domain.

Comment: Right, and my understanding was that predicates and functions were typically understood as sets of individuals, or subsets of the domain.

Comment: But in set theory, with the domain of discourse taken to be the universe of sets, functions *aren't* sets of individuals; they're just certain special individuals, so we can quantify over them. In the theory of the natural numbers, by contrast, with the domain of discourse taken to be the set of all natural numbers, a function *is* a set of individuals, and we can't quantify over functions. First-order logic allows you to quantify over individuals and not predicates, but what counts as an "individual" depends on the domain of discourse/intended interpretation.

Comment: In f-o logic we cannot quantify function and predicate **symbols**, but only *individual* variables.

Comment: In f-o set theory, the "objects" of teh domain of interpretation are *sets* and thus individual variables range over sets. Thus, we can quantify over sets. The functions and relations considered by thebtheory are *sets* and **not** symbols of the language.

Comment: What horrible things would happen if you changed the rules of FOL slightly to allow quantification over anything but propositions and predicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When studying first-order set theory, there are *two* separate notions of relation:

- Certain kinds of formulas
- Certain kinds of sets

Generally, when someone quantifies over relations (or functions or predicates) in this context, they mean the latter.

Explicitly, for any set $S$, set theory defines another set $\mathcal{P}(S)$. The quantifier "for every predicate $x$ on $S$" means "$\forall x \in \mathcal{P}(S)$".

(Yes, $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is usually given as the power set of $S$. A subset $T \subseteq S$ corresponds to the predicate "___ is in $T$")

---

Set theory is itself a form of higher-order logic. Commonly, when working in first-order set theory, one tends to use the set-theoretic incarnation of logical notions as much as possible. The few occasions when one has to fall back to the ambient first-order language, one often uses different language, such as speaking of "proper classes" or "[class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)#Classes_in_formal_set_theories)".

E.g. what you are (or seem to be) calling a "function", a set theorist would call a "class function".

Comment: The example with the power set was quite helpful. I think something just clicked, but I will have to wait and see if I can translate some sentences from my textbooks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In certain contexts of FOL, we don't typically quantify over variables of function type.

Second order logic and beyond allow this, though, so that's one formal approach.

However, note that we can use functions in FOL, and, they are simply *assumed to exist*.

This is the basis of [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form), which obviates existential quantification in favor of appropriately parameterized functions (that are assumed to exist).